# validation on ui form and restrict the words typed

Tags: validation, vue.js

i want to restrict number and symbols in fields ,  only alphabets should be typed in field

```
 var validateField = (rule, value, callback) => {
    var char = /[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+/
    if(char.test(value)) {
      callback(new Error('Please input name in English'));
    } else {
      callback()
    }
  };
```

field should accept  only alphabets , other than that nothing should be typed in field